# How to change background of ExpandableListView's items

Tags: android, expandablelistview, android-selector

I have an ExpandableListView.
When a child is expanded it should be considered "selected". When a child is selected both the child and the child's children should display a different background (to show the user which is the current selected item).

Right now this is what I have:

**XML**

```
    <ExpandableListView
        android:id="@+id/listViewAccepted"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
        android:listSelector="@drawable/custom_selector" >
    </ExpandableListView>
```

**The ListView**

```
        setOnGroupClickListener(new OnGroupClickListener() {

            @Override
            public boolean onGroupClick(ExpandableListView parent, View view,int groupPosition, long id) {
                view.setSelected(true);
                parent.setItemChecked(groupPosition, true);
                return false;
            }
        });
```

**The Selector**

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_pressed="true">
        <shape>
            <solid android:color="@color/holo_blue_light" />
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item android:state_selected="true">
        <shape>
            <solid android:color="@color/green" />
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item android:state_checked="true">
        <shape>
            <solid android:color="@color/green" />
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item android:state_focused="true">
        <shape>
            <solid android:color="@color/green" />
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item android:state_activated="true">
        <shape>
            <solid android:color="@color/green" />
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item>
        <shape>
            <solid android:color="@color/transparent" />
        </shape>
    </item>
</selector>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's how i did it, the following changes the group view. The overridden method is contained in my custom ExpandableListAdapter.

```
@Override
public View getGroupView(int groupPosition, boolean isExpanded,
        View view, ViewGroup parent)
{
    LinearLayout bevGroup = (LinearLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.myid);

    if(isExpanded)
    {
        bevGroup.setBackgroundColor(context.getResources().getColor(R.color.bgGroupBlack));
    }
    else
    {
        bevGroup.setBackgroundColor(context.getResources().getColor(R.color.bgTransparent));
    }
}
```

And the child, only ever being visible when expanded, is always the color it's supposed to be.

Comment: I had not noticed the obvious fact that the child should only have the 'selected' color as background as it is only visible when selected. Worked perfectly btw.

Comment: What is R.id.myid?

Comment: The Id of the layout resource defined in XML

Comment: Means of Child xml?

Comment: Try a tutorial, this isn't the place to teach you the most basic Android concepts.